# What is the effect of relative degree in control theory?

Tags: control-theory, stability-theory

The term of relative degree is used a lot in books of control systems. I need some explaining to understand the useful and effect of the relative degree on analysis and design the control system.
For example the following transfer function:
$$G(s)=\frac{s+1}{s^2+s+1}$$
has a relative degree one, another example the relative degree two or more. I need to know why it is important and where I have to take the relative degree in account when I design a control system.

Comment: There are several interpretations of relative degree. For example, it says about the order of the zero dynamics of the system that is the dynamics not seen from the identically zero output. Or about the achievable smoothness of the output signal, e.g., is it possible to perfectly track a discontinues signal or a continuous piecewise linear signal?

Comment: @Arastas , Ok but In which control algorithm I have to take in account the relative degree of the system?

Comment: In many of them. It is hard to answer such a general question. Tell me which algorithm you consider, then we can discuss the impact of the relative degree.

Comment: For example; algorithms of adaptive control

Comment: In adaptive control, the relative degree (r.d.) plays an important role. First, it is important to know if the system is minimum-phase or not; it is not directly the r.d., but it is related. Next, several model reference approaches are not applicable to systems with r.d. higher than 1. And some other approaches has to "compensate" the r.d., thus it must be known in advance.